# julia/gadfly multi layer in plotting, is there a python-like function?

Tags: julia, gadfly

I planned to plot some datasets in one figure, but the number of datasets is not determined (and I need to use loop to load the data from time to time). It would be extremely complex if I load all the data and set each layer in one plot function.

I saw a question here:
stackoverflow.com/questions/23857793/julia-plotting-unknown-number-of-layers-in-gadfly
However it was not perfect, I have to put them all together, and it's hard for later modification.

Is there a Python-like way to plot figures, that is, at any time you can choose the figure you are using, plot on it and switch for another later?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "modification"? You can have the list of layers to be plotted and then choose which to plot each time `plot(filter(layer_filter_function, layers))`

Comment: The most Python-like way to plot figures is to simply use [`PyPlot`](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl), which allows you to directly use matplotlib from Julia.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues/332 specially the `push!` thing.